# Strange problem in python array of object

Tags: python, arrays, class, append

I'm not really used to python and I encounter a strange (and probably stupid) problem with array of objects in python... I can't understand the problem.

I create a "Path2D" class so store a path consisting of an array of Segment2D (line segments) defined by two Point2D (A & B points with x & y coordinates each).

My Path2D class as an "appendSegment" method to add segments to the path.

Here are my classes :

```
import random
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Point2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def randomPoint(self, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
        self.x = random.uniform(xmin, xmax)
        self.y = random.uniform(ymin, ymax)
        #print(self.x,self.y)


class Segment2D:
    def __init__(self, a: Point2D, b: Point2D):
        self.A = a
        self.B = b

    def isCrossing(self, s):
        p1 = (s.A.x - s.B.x) * (self.A.y - s.A.y) - (s.A.y - s.B.y) * (self.A.x - s.A.x)
        p2 = (s.A.x - s.B.x) * (self.B.y - s.A.y) - (s.A.y - s.B.y) * (self.B.x - s.A.x)
        # if p1 & p2 are of different signs (p1p2<0) then it's crossing
        p1p2 = p1 * p2
        # print(p1, p2, p1p2)
        if p1p2 < 0:
            return (True)
        else:
            return (False)


class Path2D:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Path = []

    def printPathSegments(self):
        for s in self.Path:
            print("A (",s.A.x,",",s.A.y,") - B(",s.B.x,",",s.B.y,")")

    def appendSegment(self, s: Segment2D):
        print("segment : (", s.A.x, ",", s.A.y, ")-(", s.B.x, ",",
              s.B.y, ")")  # Print the Segment infos for debugging
        self.Path.append(s)
```

If I create several points and 2 segments that I can add to a path... Everything looks fine :

```
    A = Point2D(0, 0)
    B = Point2D(1, 0)
    S1 = Segment2D(A, B)
    C = Point2D(0.25, -0.5)
    D = Point2D(0.75, 0.5)
    S2 = Segment2D(C, D)
    MyPath2 = Path2D()
    MyPath2.appendSegment(S1)
    MyPath2.appendSegment(S2)
    MyPath2.printPathSegments()
```

It works perfectly fine. here is the output :

> segment : ( 0 , 0 )-( 1 , 0 )
>
> segment : ( 0.25 , -0.5 )-( 0.75 , 0.5 )
>
> A ( 0 , 0 ) - B( 1 , 0 )
>
> A ( 0.25 , -0.5 ) - B( 0.75 , 0.5 )

However if I now try to random segments like that (all the segments starts from the same A point) :

```
    MyPath = Path2D()
    Xmin=0.5
    Xmax=1
    Ymin=0
    Ymax=2

    Npoints = 4
    a = Point2D(0, 0)
    b = Point2D(0, 0)
    a.randomPoint(Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax)
    for i in range(Npoints):
        b.randomPoint(Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax)
        currentSegment = Segment2D(a, b)
        MyPath.appendSegment(currentSegment)
    MyPath.printPathSegments()
```

the results are weird :

> segment : ( 0.571426466187724 , 0.12306108952857064 )-(
> 0.8686174894393645 , 1.686514132982925 )
>
> segment : ( 0.571426466187724 , 0.12306108952857064 )-(
> 0.6361856198661374 , 0.05556507545768752 )
>
> segment : ( 0.571426466187724 , 0.12306108952857064 )-(
> 0.6846714628963921 , 1.9193998826107008 )
>
> segment : ( 0.571426466187724 , 0.12306108952857064 )-(
> 0.9522906125965054 , 0.6684716215164614 )
>
> A ( 0.571426466187724 , 0.12306108952857064 ) - B( 0.9522906125965054
> , 0.6684716215164614 )
>
> A ( 0.571426466187724 , 0.12306108952857064 ) - B( 0.9522906125965054
> , 0.6684716215164614 )
>
> A ( 0.571426466187724 , 0.12306108952857064 ) - B( 0.9522906125965054
> , 0.6684716215164614 )
>
> A ( 0.571426466187724 , 0.12306108952857064 ) - B( 0.9522906125965054
> , 0.6684716215164614 )

As you can see in the "segment" lines, the generated segment that is sent to appendSegment if perfectly fine.

But what is added to self.Path is wrong for the B point of each segment (the last value is used for all the segments). You can see it with the output of MyPath.printPathSegments().

I probably did something bad (and not really aware of how python 3.9 manages things in memory) but I can't understand why it works with hand-created points and not with the random points...

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for creating random objects is incorrect. You don't actually create a new object, you just change values of an existing object to new random values. So you only ever have 2 points one of which changes its value in the loop. That's why in the loop you are seeing new values, while at the end there is only last one - cause each segment consists of same 2 points.

You need to make sure each b is a new object, for example by moving `b = Point2D(0, 0)` inside the loop.

What I'd actually suggest, is define creation of random point as an alternate classmethod to `__init__`, so you can create a random point right away.

```
class Point2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    @classmethod
    def randomPoint(cls, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
        x = random.uniform(xmin, xmax)
        y = random.uniform(ymin, ymax)
        return cls(x, y)
```

Now you can create your random points directly like so:

```
a = Point2D.randomPoint(Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax)
for i in range(Npoints):
    b = Point2D.randomPoint(Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax)
    currentSegment = Segment2D(a, b)
```

Comment: Thank for the explanation ! I'm comming from a C/C++ background in which for me the difference between value and reference/pointer is clear... but in python....


At least it works perfectly

Comment: You can assume most of the objects use reference, especially ones you create yourself.